# How to connect more than one wireless headphones to one laptop?

Tags: wireless-headset

guys. I'm a language teacher and usually have to have listening tasks in my classes. I have been using wired headphones with extension jacks to connect more than 5 headphones to one laptop at the same time. I wonder how could I do the same thing with WIRELESS headphones.

Answer (score 0):

Get these things:

- Radio Headphones (I suggest fm/am combo, tough single is just fine)
- FM/AM (depends on what headphones you get) transmitter

Set all headphones and transmitter to the same frequency (unused, by law you can't use used channels and when you get a professional/bigger power transmitter, depends on country/state on wich channel by law you can chooce) and done!

If you have the headphones already, look for receivers (most popular in the area would be the ones used for tours), but be careful not to order the normal ones, since they may be using some other non fm/am frequencies, but if you buy a combo of non fm/am ones, you can get a wire from your laptop to the transmitter for tour use, if it has right size port.

Aliexpress/Alibaba or ebay are the best sources for these things.

Alternatively, if you are in a school, such what handles technology, you can ask them to make some fm or am receivers and transmitter, the schematics are easily aviable

Also if you didn't know transmitters are mostly used (cheap ones) for getting your music to car radio.